# MIPS: legal to have two consecutive "load word" instructions into the same register?

Tags: mips

**Background**: We're seeing a *very intermittent*  crash in a function `foo(int *p)`. The crash occurs while dereferencing `p`, whose value in these cases turns out to be `0xffffffff`. An analysis of the core dump shows that `foo()` is called from the following assembly snippet:

```
bne ... somewhere else
lw $a0,44(sp)
lw $a0,40(sp)
jal foo()
lui s1, 0x1000
```

Inspecting memory in the core dump shows that `44(sp)` is `0xffffffff`, whereas `40(sp)` is the correct value we intend to dereference. However, the value of `a0` at the time of the crash, inside `foo()`, is `0xffffffff`. (It's important to note that `foo()` in this case is just accessing a member; so it's literally the first instruction in `foo()` which is already attempting to access via `a0`, and crashing. Also, `ra` is pointing to the instruction following the above snippet, and `s1` currently contains `0x10000000`, so we're quite confident that `foo()` was, indeed, called from the above snippet.)

Our only theory at the moment is that the two consecutive `lw`s into `a0` are a hazard -- either a documented one, in which case this looks like a compiler bug; or an undocumented one.

**So**: is the above assembly legal? If it is, any other ideas about what could be going on here?

Thanks!

**UPDATE**: Well, turns out this was all a wild goose chase: a repeat analysis of the coredump by a colleague turned up a path in the code which I had missed, where there was a jump directly to the `jal foo()` instruction, immediately after having set `a0` to `44(sp)`. In other words, there is a path in the code which is consistent with the result we're seeing that does not involve hazards, or "skipped instructions" or anything... I thought I checked this, but I guess I either didn't, or missed it... :(

Anyway, I've accepted markgz's answer, since it answers my original question about the legality of these instructions (apparently they are).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick search of the MIPS documentation for the MIPS32R2 ISA doesn't show any restrictions on `LW` after `LW` instructions.

There *might* be a bug in the MIPS implementation in your CPU. Things to look at include:

- What address is 44(sp), 40(sp) - are they on a page boundary or a 256MByte boundary, or other interesting address?
- Do either of the loads trigger a page fault?
- Does patching the binary to insert a `NOP`, `SSNOP`, or a `SYNC` instruction between the loads make the problem go away?

Comment: Thanks! The addresses are not on any special boundary (0x17409e8 and 0x17409ec), and neither should trigger a page fault (they're both on the stack). We haven't tried patching the binary yet, our next step will be that / trying to reproduce with a minimal test case...

Comment: Interesting. That info makes a hardware bug seem less likely to me.

Comment: A reanalysis shows that the entire premise of the question was wrong... see UPDATE in the original question for the details. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: I'm glad you found what was wrong, and that it wasn't a CPU bug. Thanks for the update!